# Cant connect to specific schema in mysql

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

i'm trying to connect with jdbc to a specific schema in mysql server, the schema name is mining

when i'm trying to connect i get access to all the DB and therefore the executing statements apply to all the schemes in my db instead only to "mining"

this is how i establish a connection:

```
    public class Mining {
        Connection conn;

        void createConnection() {
            try {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); 
                this.conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:mysql://localhost/?currentSchema=mining","admin","admin" );
//I ALSO TRIED THIS:    "jdbc:mysql://localhost/mining","admin","admin"


            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

any thoughts?

thanks!

Comment: why don't you add schema name in all of your executing statements? Some thing like : `select count(*)
from myschema.mytable`
Also since you are login via admin it perhaps gets access to all the schemas.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try,

```
private Connection connect = DriverManager
              .getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/mining?"
            + "user=admin&password=admin");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String databaseURL = jdbc:mysql://hostName:portNumber/schemaName? 

Connection connectionObj = DriverManager.getConnection(databaseURL,userName,password);
```